# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'. Difficulty manipulating returned variable?

Tags: python, function, int, operand

I'm just learning to code and I'm working on a personal project to supplement my classwork - a quiz that'll also help me memorize my German vocabulary. Right now I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make this thing grade itself. Here's the code I'm trying to modify:

```
def dialogue (question,response,score):
    if question == response:
        print ("Correct! ")
        score = 1
    else:
        print ("Correct answer: " + response)
        score = 0
    return score

score = dialogue
currentScore = 0
currentScore = currentScore + score
question = raw_input ("Good morning ")
response = ("guten morgen")
dialogue(question,response,score)
print currentScore
```

My full error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Burgess/Desktop/COLLEGE FOLDER/scoreMod.py", line 12, in <module>
   currentScore = currentScore + score
   **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'**
```

All this nonsense about defining the score is getting a little lengthy. I may look at setting that up to operate as a module as well. I also want to try and convert it to give a % value feedback, but I imagine I can handle those issues on my own. Right now, I'd rather fix this problem before I complicate the code.

Anybody out there that might be able to help me figure this out? I've been lurking on the forums, and I did find one other issue with a similar title, but I don't think our problems have a similar resolution.

Comment: @vaultah: not quite, as `dialogue()` takes 3 arguments. Why it takes `score` as argument is not clear however.

Comment: And since `dialogue()` *is* being called later on it is not clear at all why `score = dialogue` is there *at all*.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell which version of Python you are using and comment your code. Please explain why you wrote the code that way.

Here is the revised version with comments that will work in Python 2.7.

```
def dialogue(question,response): # you are defining dialogue as a function
    # This function checks whether the answer matches the correct answer
    if question.lower() == response.lower(): # .lower() makes it not case sensitive
        print ("Correct! ")
        return 1 # If matches, return 1
    else:
        print ("Correct answer: " + response)
        return 0 # If does not match, return 0

currentScore = 0 # Initial Score

question = raw_input("Good morning: ") #Asking for input
response = "guten morgen" #Correct answer

currentScore += dialogue(question, response) #calling the function with 2 arguments
#adding the returned score to currentScore
"""
currentScore += dialogue(question, response)
is same as
currentScore = currentScore + dialogue(question, response)
"""
print currentScore #returning output
```

And here is the code without comments:

```
def dialogue(question,response): 
    if question.lower() == response.lower():
        print ("Correct! ")
        return 1
    else:
        print ("Correct answer: " + response)
        return 0 

currentScore = 0

question = raw_input("Good morning: ")
response = "guten morgen"

currentScore += dialogue(question, response)
print currentScore
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, try this code firstly. If You work with 3.X version You shouldn't use raw_input.
Try use x.upper() if You want compare two sentence.

```
def dialogue (question,response):
    if question == response:
        print ("Correct! ")
        score = 1
    else:
        print ("Incorrect answer: " + response)
        score = 0
    return score
currentScore = 0
question = input("Good morning ")
question='Good morning'
response='guten morgen'
score = dialogue(question,response)
currentScore = currentScore + score
print ('Your score:',(currentScore))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are assigning the method to a variable and not actually calling the method. In your example `score = dialogue` should be replaced by something like 
 `score = dialogue(question,response,score)`